# Handling premature client disconnection in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am currently testing out aiohttp and I am having a problem with the following code:

```
async def index(request: web.Request) -> web.StreamResponse:
    response = web.StreamResponse(headers={'content-type': 'text/plain'})
    await response.prepare(request)
    for i in range(1000000):
        try:
            response.write(b'test response')
            await response.drain()
        except concurrent.futures.CancelledError:
            print('Remote connection closed... Cleaning up...')
            # Do cleanup process here?
            raise

    return response
```

Now I try this out with the following curl request:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

And then I hit Ctrl-C to cause curl to disconnect and stop downloading the response.

On the console log from the aiohttp web server I get **a lot** of the following:

```
2017-11-08 14:42:31,295|WARNING|asyncio|socket.send() raised exception.
2017-11-08 14:42:31,295|WARNING|asyncio|socket.send() raised exception.
2017-11-08 14:42:31,295|WARNING|asyncio|socket.send() raised exception.
2017-11-08 14:42:31,295|WARNING|asyncio|socket.send() raised exception.
2017-11-08 14:42:31,295|WARNING|asyncio|socket.send() raised exception.
```

Which keeps looping and I cannot kill the server with Ctrl-C. I have to kill it with `kill -KILL` in order to fully terminate it. It seems that the client socket disconnection is silently handled. I would like to silence the above warnings which are thrown by `asyncio.selector_events._SelectorSocketTransport.write()`. I could silence that by setting the appropriate logger level, but that's not what I want. Plus there's a lot of cleanup procedures that I would like to do when a client connection terminates. I have looked through the aiohttp code and there doesn't seem to be any handlers or signals that I can hook into to handle it. Ideally I would like to be able to do some cleanup when a client connection is closed.

In Django I am able to do it by creating a custom `SelfCleaningStream` class with the `StreamingHttpResponse` class. The custom `SelfCleaningStream` class handles the cleanup in the `close()` method which is called by Django when a client connection is closed.

Comment: Not sure if it's final answer, but you should certainly use `asyncio.CancelledError` instead of `concurrent.futures.CancelledError` - these are different classes.

Comment: Actually I've tried it with both those exceptions in a tuple. Neither one gets thrown, and it appears this is a bug in aiohttp. In the meantime I have worked around it by checking `request.protocol.transport.is_closing()` before `response.write()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for report.
It is a bug in aiohttp, I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2499)